# Errors appending to a table in Access VBA

Tags: sql, json, vba, ms-access

I have an Access database with a VBA module that assembles a JSON string in a variable: `JsonStr2` that I want to place in a simple table: `JSONforAPI` with two fields:

- `ID` = Auto number and
- `JSON` = Long String.

The JSON is valid and `Jsonstr2` prints in the immediate window on `Debug.Print`.

When I run the code line:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO JSONforAPI (JSON) VALUES (" & Jsonstr2 & ")"
```

I get:

> Run time error ‘3075’ Malformed GUID in query expression ‘{"order":{"CustomerID":"19"’.”

On clicking Help I get:

> This command isn’t available. Your organization’s administrator turned off the service required to use this feature.

I get the same even if I create a Query Def.

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are concatenating your value with the remainder of your SQL statement, none of the delimiters or other special characters within the string held by `Jsonstr2` will be escaped and therefore you'll end up with all kinds of malformed strings within the SQL statement.

You should instead use parameters to avoid the need to escape the string, e.g.:

```
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("","insert into jsonforapi (json) values (@json)")
    .Parameters("@json") = jsonstr2
    .Execute
End With
```

Comment: Elegant, short and SAFE

Comment: Thank you so much for your speedy reply. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO JSONforAPI (JSON) VALUES ('" & Jsonstr2 & "')"
```

This will single quote Jsonstr2.

As you did not quote the string, it is passed as GUID, not a simple string.

Comment: With great pleasure.

Comment: What happens if `jsonstr2` contains a single quote?

Comment: In json string, we usually quote with double  quote " both field name and value. My solution is only valid in case without single quote in string Jsonstr2. In the latter case single quote must be escaped.